# MySQL: Transfer duplicate records to another table, during INSERT `tablename` SELECT * FROM `data source`

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a transition from `MS Access` into `MySQL`.
With Access,  I can copy and paste data between tables, any duplicates will  be automatically placed in the table `paste_errors`. How can I accomplish this in `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [creating a `Trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940506/mysql-on-duplicate-key-insert) which will outline two ways to do it.